# Countdown timer without app running

Tags: ios, timer

In objective C, I want to countdown timer start from user has first launch and after 24 hours, an alert will be showed not dependent on user quit app or not.
The problem appear when user change device date time.
If I use a server to store date time first launch, then the problem if user turn off network when first launch.
Do you have any solution to do that? Thank you!

Comment: if you dont want to rely on system time why dont use a NTP server to get network time.

Answer (score 0):

An immediate solution that comes to mind is notifications.

Either a scheduled notification on the device, which is subject to the user not changing the date/time on their device. Or a server could decide when the 24 hour period has expired and send out a push notification to the device, although this will rely on the user not turning off push notification.

These are the two options available to you and you will need to pick the one which best suits your needs.

Comment: I've try with UIlocalNotification 

But the problem if user change device date time.

Comment: Then you will need to use a push notification, the server will decide when the 24 hours are up and will send the push notification

Comment: yes, but how about they don't connect wifi or cellular data? Then device can't receive notification.

Comment: Yes that's correct. I have edited my answer to reflect this. What is the reason for wanting to alert the user after 24 hours?

Comment: My app has function sell off if they buy in 24h after first app launch.

Comment: Ok so it needs to be secure. In that case I would definitely use the server to send a push notification.